# Send data between components in ReactJs using Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

According to the documentation, GraphQl provides state management like Redux. I have 2 components. In the `Component1` i get data from the server using AppoloClient, it works ok, and in the `Component2` i want to read data from the `cache`(store).

```js
//Component1
import React from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  query GetExchangeRates {
    rates(currency: "EUR") {
      currency
    }
  }
`;

const Component1 = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EXCHANGE_RATES);
  console.log("component1", data);

  return <div>Component1</div>;
};

export default Component1;

//Component2
import React from 'react';
import {gql} from "@apollo/client";
import {client} from "./App";

const Component2 = () => {
    const info = client.readQuery({
        query: gql`
            query EXCHANGE_RATES {
                rates(currency: "EUR") {
                    currency
                }
            }
        `,
    });
    console.log('component2',info);
    return (
        <div>
          component2
        </div>
    );
};

export default Component2;
```

Issue: I can get data in component 1, but when I try to read data from component 2, I get `undefined`. 
Question: How to solve this to be able to read data that is fetched in component 1, in component 2? Also how in GraphQl and Apollo client to pass an object for example in the cache, and to read this in component 1(like redux functionality)? 
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sun-symv6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: use the same `useQuery` but with 'cache-only' fetch policy ... local state - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/local-state-management/

Comment: @xadm, could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752428/get-data-from-a-query-in-reactjs-using-graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo provides **client**-side state handling which **can** be set up to handle your client site state in the same we you do it with your **server**-side state.

In your example this is not what you want. Recently there is a noticeable shift in the react community that server side data should not be stored in your global state handling tool of choice. Your fetching tool (in your case apollo) should handle this by caching the responses.

To solve your problem, where both components are using the exact same query, you should just do that. Run the query twice and let apollo handle the caching. So you could pull out the query to a query file or just create a useRates hook and import that in your component to even better share the logic between your components.

To answer why your approach is not working you have to understand that your lookup in the cache is happening at a time before your request has even finished and that this cache look up is not "reactive".

Edit: I just got this out fast to provide a starting point and can clean this up later if things got cleared up.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you also help me related to the second issue: `how to send data in the cache(store) from component 1 and to get this data in component 2`? EX: const obj = {name: "John"} to be sent from component 1 and to access this obj in component 2.

Comment: you can look up local state management here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/local-state-management/ but you should not use it to share fetched data. Tanner linsley made a good point about real client side state here https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/does-this-replace-client-state if you want to read up about that.

Comment: could you help please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752428/get-data-from-a-query-in-reactjs-using-graphql , it will help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

When the **App** mounts, both of your component's data are empty.

Then apollo fetches the data with **useQuery**. And your component1's state got changed. Because of that, component1 re-render and log the new data.

But there is no state on your component2 that changed. So, component2 does not re-render.

To solve this, you can run **useQuery** hook with the same query on the component2 again, by default apollo will provide you the data from the Cache.

Comment: could you please show how to send data in the cache(store) from component 1 and to get this data in component 2? EX: const obj = {name: "John"} to be sent from component 1 and to access this obj in component 2.

Comment: You don't need to send the data, apollo will store the data in the cache. Just run the same query again on your component2.

Comment: could you help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752428/get-data-from-a-query-in-reactjs-using-graphql?noredirect=1#comment118001025_66752428