# Get data from a query in ReactJs using GraphQl

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I use Apollo Client and have the next code:

```js
import {InMemoryCache, makeVar} from "@apollo/client";

export const cartItemsVar = makeVar(['test']);
export const demo3 = makeVar({name: 123});

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: true,
    typePolicies: {
        Person: {
            fields: {
                nameCar: {
                    read(name) {
                        return demo3();
                    }
                }
            }},
        Query: {
            fields: {
                cartItems: {
                    read() {
                        return cartItemsVar();
                    }
                },
                demo: {
                  merge(name) {
                     return demo3()
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How you can notice, this is my store in my react application. I want to get data from

```js
Person: {
  fields: {
    nameCar: {
      read(name) {
        return demo3();
      }
    }
  }
},
```

But doing something like this

```js
const GET_CART_ITEMS = gql `
    query GetCartItems {
        nameCar @client
    }
`;
//

const {
  data,
  loading,
  error
} = useQuery(GET_CART_ITEMS);
```

... i get `undefined` in `data`., but if i do

```js
export const GET_CART_ITEMS = gql `
    query GetCartItems {
        cartItems @client
    }
`;
```

...i get the wanted result `cartItems: ["test"]`.
Question: How to get data `{name: 123}` in the first situation and why the code does not work?  What is the difference inside the `typePolicies` between `Person` and `Query`?

Comment: `Query` is a root type, field can be queried 'independently' while  `nameCar` can be used in query where result on some 'depth level' is a Person type ... `getPerson(id) { id name nameCar @client }`

Comment: @xadm , Could YOU show how to get the values from Person?

Comment: @xadm could you show me the code because I don’t understand how to get that data?

Comment: `Person` can be a BE type (response/return type for some query) ... or local in schema https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/client-side-schema/ ... `type Person { nameCar: String }  .... extend type Query .... getPerson: Person` ... search for some tutorial ?